Can R display and control the Windows 11 Command Prompt?
I would like an R program to bring up the Windows 11 Command Prompt, navigate to a particular directory, and issue the 'dir' command. Following this the Command Prompt window will stay up, visible to the user. Is this possible?
Note: I am well aware of the R 'system' and 'system2' commands, but they do not cause the Command Prompt to stay up, visible to the user. If you set invisible=FALSE the Command Prompt flashes for a fraction of a second, then goes away.

try
shell('start cmd.exe /K "dir"')


Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I can also go to the desired directory by using the 'start' command's /d switch.
